# Opera <audio /> is flash? HTML5

Tags: reactjs, html5-audio, opera

Ok this has me wondering what have I done, either reactjs/nodejs is turning my perfect html5 app into a flash app.

without my knowledge or Opera GX thinks it needs to play audio files through a flash plugin.

It is basically stopping autoplay due to the fact that users need to allow flash before the audio will play (unless they click the play button)

Can someone please explain to me why or how this is. and what I can do to correct this?

to clarify my audio tag is

```
<audio id="player" autoPlay>
            <source src="StartOfTrevda.mp3"
                type="audio/mpeg"
            />
        </audio>
```